# Update en MySQl "Rango de Fechas"

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Buen día comunidad, les comparto mi situación estoy intentado modificar una columna pero solo en determinados renglones ejemplo tengo una tabla llamada fechas y genero multiples fechas que le corresponde un mismo id entonces lo que quiero hacer es que me edite la columna "estado" únicamente en el rango de la fecha mínima y el día de hoy y las fechas posteriores no las modifique no se si me di a entender estoy tratando con varias consulta pero esta es una de las que quería aplicar pero me marca error.
Gracias

```
UPDATE fechas SET estado='editado' WHERE fecha in (select * from fechas WHERE (fecha BETWEEN (select distinct min(fecha) from fechas where idVisitas=458) AND current_date()) );
```

Comment: que error? y porque no usas un where directamente?

Comment: @gbianchi me marca este error en la consulta que te muestro Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: el error te dice que no podes usar la tabla fechas como subconsulta.. lo cual es logico porque es la tabla que estas modificando.. e igual, no entiendo la logica de tener una subconsulta que tiene exactamente el where que queres...

Comment: el error anteriro fue como me comentaste que hiciera directamente el where

Comment: habria que ver como lo escribiste.. asi no tiene mucha logica tu consulta...

Comment: UPDATE fechas SET estado='editado' 
 WHERE (fecha BETWEEN (select distinct min(fecha)mini from fechas where idVisitas=458) AND current_date());

Comment: asi la escribi ya mas simple o no se que otra manera me permita sacar ese rango

Comment: no entiendo tus condiciones... la fecha minima es despreciable si pones como condicion un idVisitas, porque el minimo de ese id y la fecha de hoy, son todas las fechas para ese id... Por lo tanto, no tiene nada de sentido la condicion de min(fecha).. solo alcanza con ese id y que como maximo sea la fecha de hoy...

Comment: lo que pasa que ese mismo tiene mas fechas, yo solo quiero editar las fechas que ya pasaron de ese id

Comment: y por eso.. el minimo no te importa, porque con poner las fechas menores a hoy son todas las fechas desde la primera para ese id... no hay menos que el minimo, asi que no importan.. otra cosa es si fueras de una fecha en particular.. pensa esto.. es posible que ese id tenga una fecha menor a la fecha que figura como min(fecha) para ese id?

Comment: entonces como me recomiendas hacer la consulta

Comment: where fecha < fechahoy and id = ?

Comment: tienes razon gracias por el aporte, creo se me nublo un poco la solucion, Gracias